# Vue 3: Add global method via Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to build a method that can be used inside any template to automatically build local image urls.

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to build a plugin that adds a global property, it's not working!

Plugin code

```
// src/plugins/urlbuilder.js
export default {
    install: (app) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.buildImageUrl = imageName => require('@/assets/images/' + imageName);
    }
}
```

Main.js file

```
// src/main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import urlbuilder from './plugins/urlbuilder.js'

createApp(App).use(router).use(urlbuilder).mount('#app')
```

Home view where I render the image

```
// src/views/Home.vue
<template>
    <img :src="buildImageUrl('myimage.jpg')">
</template>
```

and I'm getting this error in my the dev console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.buildImageUrl is not a function
    at Proxy.render (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=template&id=fae5bece&scoped=true:57)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:922)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4667)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:195)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4793)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4576)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4534)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4138)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4744)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:195)
```

**Note:** This works when I add purely a global property, but I read the best way to do this was via plugin.

It works when I do this:

```
app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.buildImageUrl = imageName => require('@/assets/images/' + imageName)

app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `import urlbuilder from './plugins/urlbuilder'`

Comment: @Naren didn't work :/ Gave the previous error.

Answer (score 1):

You should get global properties by this:

```js
  const instance = getCurrentInstance()
  const globalProperties = instance.appContext.config.globalProperties
  console.log(globalProperties)
```

> Recommand use provide and inject.

Or use a hook:

`useGlobalProps.ts`

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
import type { ComponentInternalInstance } from 'vue'

function useGlobalProps() {
  const { appContext } = getCurrentInstance() as ComponentInternalInstance
  const globalProps = appContext.config.globalProperties
  return { ...globalProps }
}

export default useGlobalProps
```

use it in component:

```js
import useGlobalProps  from '@/hooks/useGlobalProps'
const { testFn, globalFn } = useGlobalProps()
testFn()
globalFn('global function in main.js')
```

Register `globalFn` in main.js

```js
app.config.globalProperties.globalFn = function testGlobal(name: string) {
  console.log(name)
}
```

Register `testFn` by plugin:

`myPlugin.js`

```js
export default function (app: App<HTMLElement>) {
  app.config.globalProperties.testFn = () => {
    console.log('install global properties')
  }
  return app
}
```

use plugin in main.js

```js
import myPlugin from './myPlugin.js'
// ...
app.use(myPlugin)
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use provide and inject

```
import urlbuilder from './plugins/urlbuilder.js'

app.provide('$urlbuilder', urlbuilder);
```

Read more about [provide and inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#app-level-provide)